# iPhone 4 falling in water - issues after fixing

Tags: iphone, repair

Two months ago, I accidentally dropped my iPhone 4 into water (for 3 seconds or so). Immediately I turned it off and put it in a bowl of rice. After two days, I took it to a repair shop, in which it was dried and fixed (headphones didn't work after the accident).

It was "fine" after that, but since then I've been experiencing some weird issues:

- GPS isn't working well for navigation (can't seem to locate accurately, tell speed or direction).
- When the battery is less than 1/4, it suddenly turns off. I have to wait like 10 minutes before turning it on again, and then it turns on normally.
- The battery drains way faster than it used to.
- A little blue stain has appeared on the screen.

What I want to know is if it is possible that all these issues are related to the accident I had and if/how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, even likely, that one or more of these issues was caused by immersing the iPhone in water. You should seek repair quotes from Apple or [other repair sources](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=iPhone%20repair&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), but you'll most likely find that replacing the phone is the most economical solution. Check Craigslist and similar places for people selling their iPhone 4's after upgrading to a 4s.

If you're of a DIY mindset, [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/) provides repair information, parts and tools for fixing portable electronics.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to fix the GPS at least? I don't really understand how that kind of thing can "break".

Comment: Water, or more accurately mineral deposits and contaminants contained in the water, create an electrical short circuit allowing power or signal to flow along paths it isn't supposed to. The GPS is part of the 3G radio chip so my best guess–as a person who hasn't seen your phone and is not at all qualified to make a complex diagnosis–is that a failure of the GPS is indicative of major problems and, as I stated in the answer, that unit is most likely **BER** (beyond economical repair—unless you can DIY) or, as we tech-types say colloquially, *toast*

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't have a more optimistic answer. Also, I now see you're not here in the US, so I apologize for providing such a US-centric response, but it's really the only point of reference I have. Best of luck getting this sorted.

Comment: Somehow I knew that would be the answer, so don't worry. Thanks for your time!